Subjective Judgement on Similarity: Mathematical Expression
I am a student currently studying Behavioral Economics. Recently, I’ve been exploring case-based decision theory (CBDT), which heavily relies on the concept of a "similarity function" to quantitatively measure the level of similarity between two objects. However, CBDT itself doesn't tell me the specific form of this function. Since I haven't studied Psychology systematically, I’m curious to know: is there a specific similarity function that is widely accepted or commonly used among psychologists?
I would also greatly appreciate it if anyone could recommend literature reviews, papers, or books that discuss similarity functions from a psychological perspective.
